# Cinema4D for game development tutorials anyone?

Tags: 3d-modeling, cinema4d

I started to learn Cinema 4D. 
I've noticed it's really easy to use for motion graphics, but I want to use
it for modeling for games/realtime 3d engines.

Before I used 3dsmax and it was easy to estimate how a model would look/behave in a 3d engine.
The two main things I did was **displaying Polygon triangles** and **displaying the Polygon Count**.

I've found the Total Polygons tick in HUD settings in Cinema 4D, but
I can't find any display mode that will show triangles.

**Is there there a way to display triangle faces/not quads in Cinema4D ?
If so how ?**

There is a Triangulate function, but I'd rather not Triangulate/Untriangulate all the time,
especially since it's converting back and forth between the two doesn't always produce the same result.

Comment: You may also be interested checking http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's aprox 2x the quads number, more or less, so...

Anyway, imho is like driving or dancing, better to go "getting the feel" than be very obsessed with the number there. These days optimizing is important, but not us much as the high quality of the art being produced... Indeed, is the time of high end modeling... You might be modeling for phones, etc, and yep, there's still needed a lot of low pol.

Anyway, I'd recommend Cinema specially for rendering, maybe animation if purchase the special module for it... But for modeling... I'd prefer Blender, Silo, Modo or Wings.

Anyway, I don't know you, but I myself when doing low pol am not all time looking at polycount numbers... Is more about making the polies efficient, don't waste them (But i optimize at the end, I don't let that get in the middle of the creative procces) and if are not much restricted by a polygon budget, sometimes is better to use some more if it's gonna make a cleaner UV layout for texturing... Or for joints bending, etc. Quads are better for both texturing and animation. (though in the end it's all tris, is more a matter of workflow, and indeed, quads make modeling easier, and better organized wires)

Anyway, I am not sure if [game development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange is better suited for this... It's certainly not off topic here, you can ask as many as you wish, but I am not sure(sincerely) if there you might be heard by a higher number of experts in that area. Though I am not sure if the people there is more of programming nature than (like myself) , game artists.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very insightful. You are right about focusing on the decent models vs. low poly. I am interested in using these models for the web and mobile. Here's an example of low-poly models for web(http://disturbmedia.com/blog/post/exploring-threejs-part-1-exporting-models-from-cinema-4d-to-javascript/). Performance will improve, but at the moment I'm interested in delivering models that don't slow 3D scenes too much. Speaking of   stack exchange, wishing more people committed to 3D Graphics Techniques and Software

Comment: Yep, totally agree about G.D., but seems artists -except me and some other- wander more around other places. I am lately _very_ interested in webgl + javascript for 3D... Reading that link...I'd have kept with Blender, and even 2.5x... ;)  It's free...You can use groups for selection tags, and other 2.56 beta features...Asigning materials is not either super complex...I'm a Blender user ;). The issue I see with all these engines is Webgl only working in ffox 4 beta or crhome 9 beta, I think latest safari, also... I like to play with stuff massively adopted by users...Quite interested, though.

Comment: Unsure on if this can be of use for you :  http://code.google.com/p/blender-webgl-exporter/